# measure theory, $\delta$-$\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, epsilon-delta

I am struggling with this exercise:

> Suppose that $f \in L^1(\Omega, A, \mu)$. Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $\mu(E) < \delta \rightarrow\int_E|f| \mu<\epsilon$.

Since I know that f is integrable, I know that $\int_\Omega|f|d\mu=K<\infty$. If this K is zero, I see that I allready have what I want, so I can assume that K is bigger than zero.

I am having a problem since I don't know if the function is bounded, had the function been bounded by a number M, I could just choose $\delta=\epsilon/(2\cdot M)$.

I think the $\delta$ should be a function of K and $\epsilon$ somehow.

Any tips?

Comment: Hint: Approximate $|f|$ from below by step functions.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks, I've tried that but I still get stuck: Let $h_n \rightarrow |f|$ pointwise. Then I try to integrate a step function: $\int_Eh_n d\mu=\Sigma_{i=1}^{K_n}a_i^n\mu(A_i^n\cap E)$, here n is just the index for the function-number n in the converging sequence, it is not an exponent. But the problem with $\Sigma_{i=1}^{K_n}a_i^n\mu(A_i^n\cap E)$, is that even though I have a very strict requirement of the measure of E, the $a_i$'s, can blow up.

Comment: The idea is (cf. the answer below) to take a step function $h_n$ with $\int |f| - h_n < \varepsilon /2$. Then $h_n$ is fixed (so that nothing blows up) and you are reduced to showing the claim (for $\varepsilon/2$) for $h_n$ (why?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the statement would be trivial if the function $f$ were bounded.

So set $f_n(x) = f(x)$ if $f(x) \leq n$ and $f(x) = n$ otherwise.  Then each $f_n$ is bounded and converges to $f$ point wise.  By the monotone convergence theorem, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $\int_E f - \int_E f_N < \epsilon/2$.  So choose $\delta < \epsilon/(2N)$.  If $\mu(A) < \delta$, we have that

$\int_A f = \int_A (f - f_N) + \int_A f_N < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2$ as needed.